# HAProxy ACLs on front end send to different backend

Tags: reverse-proxy, haproxy

I have a High Available HAProxy loadbalancer setup with keepalived configured.

On my front end, I would like to set up different ACLs which look at the URI path sent to HAProxy and I would like to send the request to a specific backend based on the path.

The reason is that I have 4 different pairs of web apps which I would like to make reachable via the HAProxy VIP.

I have managed to make this work for one of the web applications but adding more is not working.

If I navigate to http://haproxy_ip:port/pulse the web app from backend pulse is loading.

If I navigate to http://haproxy_ip:port/pulse_tim I get a 404 not found error.

The web apps configured in the backend are all reachable via `http://ip:port/pulse`.

```
frontend http_front
bind haproxy_ip:port
stats uri /haproxy?stats
acl is_pulse_uri path_beg /pulse
acl is_pulse_uri_tim path_beg /pulse_tim
use_backend pulse if is_pulse_uri
use_backend pulse_tim if is_pulse_uri_tim
default_backend http_back

backend http_back
balance roundrobin
hash-type consistent djb2
stick-table type string len 32 size 1M peers LB
stick on req.cook(JSESSIONID)
stick store-response res.cook(JSESSIONID)
server host1 xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx check cookie host1
server host2 xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx check cookie host2

backend pulse
server pulse ip:port check
server pulse ip:port check backup

backend pulse_tim
server pulse_tim ip:port check
server pulse_tim ip:port check backup
```

Is this actually not working because my web app resides under `http://ip:port/pulse` and when I try to match the /pulse_tim URI then haproxy forwards this to the backend server like `http://pulse_tim_ip:port/pulse_tim` instead of `http://pulse_tim:port/pulse`?

If yes, how can I look for URIs in ACLs and rewrite how the request is forwarded to the backend?

Thanks!